# Restricting minimum length of email ONLY for Gmail logins Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

So, there is a task to match emails in an input agains some certain conditions. Most of them are fulfilled. All of them, actually, except one.

So, user emails have to be up to 30 characters long, but they cannot be shorter than 6 only for gmail users (the part before the @). Other types of email can have even shorter emails.

Please help me find a correct regexp!

My current one is:

```
^((?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\.]{1,30})\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a case insensitive match, you could write the pattern as:

```
^(?!.*?\.\.)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,30}@(?!gmail\.com$)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}|[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6,30}@gmail\.com)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*?\.\.)` Assert not `..` to the right
- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `[a-z0-9.]{1,30}` Match 1-30 chars specified in the character class
  - `@(?!gmail\.com$)` Match @ and assert not followed by gmail.com
  - `(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}` Match 1+ repetitions of the character class and `.` and match 2-4 chars of the second character class
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6,30}@gmail\.com`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFgUwE/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*?\.\.)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,30}@(?!gmail\.com$)(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}|[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6,30}@gmail\.com)$/i;
[
  "testing@test.com",
  "t@gmail.com",
  "t@test.com",
  "testing@gmail.com"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

A bit shorter way to write it could be asserting not 1-5 characters before gmail.com:

```
^(?!.*?\.\.)(?![a-z0-9.]{1,5}@(?=gmail\.com$))[a-z0-9.]+@(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a0hpJ3/1)

Comment: Yes, no, I am so sorry, but it doesn't work. It should Allow emails shorter than 6 characters for NON gmail and NOT allow GMAIL to be shorter than 6 characters before @. Your option doesn't do that.

Comment: @Not-a-Whale The question states `user emails have to be up to 30 characters long, but they cannot be shorter than 6 only for gmail users` so only for gmail users they can be shorter than 6. Can you update this regex demo https://regex101.com/r/K4v5VM/1 with strings that should and should not match?

Comment: Gmail - non shorter than 6 characters. Non-gmail - can be shorter than 6 characters before @. I am sorry maybe I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Not-a-Whale So it should be like this then? https://regex101.com/r/kFgUwE/1

Comment: Oh I am sorry again! It totally works! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: @Not-a-Whale Do you mean the link that I just posted in the comments or the already existing answer?

Comment: Actually the link probably works the best of three options

Comment: @Not-a-Whale Ok, I have updated the answer. Glad it works for you :-)